# Several lines instructions

Tags: vimscript

Is there a way to split a one-line instruction into several lines?

For example, I'd like to transform

```
setlocal variable_name = condition1 ? "1" : condition2 ? "0" : condition3 ? "a long string" : "another long string"
```

into

```
setlocal variable_name = condition1 ? "1" : 
                         condition2 ? "0" : 
                         condition3 ? "a long string" : 
                                      "another long string"
```

but when I try it like above, it raises "Invalid argument" error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To have multiple lines in a vimscript you need to prepend the next lines with `\`

```
setlocal variable_name = condition1 ? "1" : 
                       \ condition2 ? "0" : 
                       \ condition3 ? "a long string" : 
                       \              "another long string"
```